# refuse to apply style and tinyMC / angular 6 application

Tags: angular, tinymce

I have integrated tinyMCE 5.2.1 (angular 6 application ) as below.

Angular.json

```
"styles":[
"node_modules/tinymce/skins/content/default/content.min.css", 
]
"scripts":[
 "node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.min.js",
 "node_modules/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js"  
]
```

in .ts file I have configured as below :

```
 tinymce.init({
      selector: '.TinyMCE',
      skin: false,
      content_css: 'assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.min.css',
      mode: 'exact',
      height: 150,
      schema: 'html5',
      menubar: false,
      theme: 'silver',
      statusbar: false,
      plugins: 'placeholder',
      content_style:
        '#tinymce-body { min-height: 0px; } .mce-content-body { color: rgba(101, 99, 93, 1); overflow-x: hidden !important; }',
      body_id: 'tinymce-body',
      toolbar: 'bold underline italic addAttachment',
      //valid_elements: 'strong/b,i/italic,p,br',
      inline_styles: false,
      formats: {
        // bold: { inline: 'span', classes: 'bold' },
        // italic: { inline: 'span', classes: 'em' },
        // underline: { inline: 'span', classes: 'underline', exact: true },
        underline: { inline: 'u', exact: true },
        italic: { inline: 'em', exact: true },
        bold: { inline: 'b', exact: true }
      },
      elements: this.elementID,
      setup: this.tinyMCESetup.bind(this),
      //  setup: this.getSetup,
    });
```

before adding skin.min.css to styles array in angular.json I had following things in assets array of angular.json

```
 {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/tinymce/skins",
                "output": "/skins/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/tinymce/themes",
                "output": "/themes/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/tinymce/plugins",
                "output": "/plugins/"
              },
```

This was working well in chrome but it did not worked in IE11 as it was not getting rendered at all, however after this I removed above part and pasted skin.min.css directly under styles array of angular.json, this made tinyMCE to be worked in both IE & Chrome but it does give below error in console of chrome :

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/gateway/api/portal/mysite/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Please let me know if someone has foun similr issue.

Comment: I have the same in React project on conditional rendering